# Is there a way to update Apple AdHoc provision profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have recently created a new certificate for my own profile but there are already development and AdHoc provisioning profiles exist. So now I want to include my newly created certificate into those provision profiles.
In Apple Developer portal I could edit "Development Provision Profile" and tick my certificate to include it into that provision profile but I do not see such option for AdHoc profile.
So my question is, can I include my newly created certificate into the existing AdHoc profile?
Because currently when I try to manually sign my project I get this warning in Xcode:

```
Provisioning profile "match AdHoc com.example" doesn't include signing certificate 
"Apple Development: My Name (some_code_here)".
```

and when I click on info button I get this:

```
Doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: My Name (some_code_here)"
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: For Adhoc you can only use one distrubution certificate and also you need to create a distribution certificate to sign a AdHoc profile, you cannot sign adhoc with development profile